# Data Table has null values

Tags: .net, database, vb.net, datatable

on `FbuildingSettings.vb` - Form

```
Public camButtonDtable As DataTable
```

Then I used it in `Fbuilding.vb` - Form

```
Dim names = From row In FbuildingSettings.camButtonDtable.AsEnumerable() Select row.Field(Of String)("Building") Distinct
    For Each word In names
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(word)
    Next
```

Pretty much do what I want, *get each of the distinct data from a column*. So I used that code in `FbuildingSettings.vb`

```
Dim names = From row In camButtonDtable.AsEnumerable() Select row.Field(Of String)("Building") Distinct
    For Each word In names
        comboBuilding.Items.Add(word)
    Next
```

I get the error:
[image]
Tried this : `Public camButtonDtable As New DataTable` - it did compiled, but the comboBox does not display a thing.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: any chance `camButtonDtable` has not been populated yet?

Comment: well, my database have 3 datas on it. And when I try to run `FbuildingSettings` the data table has been populated even if I did not run the form, but when I run the form where it was declared, it says its null, that's where I lost. haha

Comment: It doesn't matter what you've got in your database.  If you don't retrieve that data from the database and populate that DataTable then of course you'll not see any data because the DataTable is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution *(this is the one I used)*:

```
FbuildingSettings.camButtonDtable = databaseFunctions.GetDataTable(queryBtn) 'to iniatialize data on cambtndtable
```

This should be something like this *(not really sure)*:

```
Dim queryBtn As String = "SELECT * FROM tblCameraButtons"
FbuildingSettings.camButtonDtable = <DataTable>.Fill(queryBtn)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Cause**

1. Your title is irrelevant to the thrown exception.
2. At this point, the problem is not whether or not the `DataTable` is populated, but rater if the `DataTable` is instantiated.
3. Your `DataTable` is not instantiated.

Your error occurs at:

```
<DataTable>.AsEnumerable()
```

From reflector, *System.Linq.Enumerable*:

```
Public Shared Function AsEnumerable(Of TSource)(ByVal source As IEnumerable(Of TSource)) As IEnumerable(Of TSource)
    Return source
End Function
```

**Solution**

1. Make sure the table exists.
2. Ensure that the table are properly initialized.

```
Public Class FbuildingSettings

    Public Sub New()
        Me.InitializeComponent()
        Me.camButtonDtable = New DataTable()
        Me.camButtonDtable.Columns.Add("Building", GetType(String))
        Me.camButtonDtable.AcceptChanges()
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly camButtonDtable As DataTable

End Class
```

Comment: As I have said, using the `New` code lets me compile the app but that does not solve the problem, though its compiling, there were no items in the `comboBox` although I used the same code and principle from the other form. One thing that I am really confused is that, `camButtonDtable` was declared on form which this error is happening, but not on the other.