# Compare Data from app to database

Tags: .net, vb.net, ms-access

I am not so good in sql, so I wanted to ask how can I compare a specific data to "foo".
[image]

1. user will input a unique ID
2. choose mortality date
3. the system will check if the id is existing;
4. then if its existing, it will check if the *pig* is from the chosen *Batch From:*`ComboBox` = `CurrentLocation` (*fieldname*)
5. if the `CurrentLocation` of the pig is not the same as the item in comboBox = error input

So basically, I need to check the `CurrentLocation`- (*database field*) of the user input item and compare in to `ComboBatchFrom.Text`
I have tested some [methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21541738/check-if-column-is-empty), but its not working, thus also far from my goal. I hope you can give me some ideas on how to get the data from access. thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21541738/check-if-column-is-empty - this but it seems not right. its not working.

Comment: looking at your other question, have you checked the Row Count of  `tablePiglet` to see if it is greater than zero? i.e. `tablePiglet.Rows.Count`

Comment: yes, and the count is not greater than 0. in fact as I have stated there, I feel like the data table is not existing, yet its there. I still haven't solved that problem, but this question, yet I think is a different one, *(so I asked)* this is the goal that I need to accomplish today.

Comment: if the Count is not greater than 0, that means your DataTable has no row at the moment, except you have strong proof telling otherwise. [Any chance DataTable hasn't been populated yet](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21347632/2998271)? by calling `.Fill` function [maybe](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21421329/2998271)?

Comment: @AdorableVB can you show the code that you are using to populate your DataTable? because if you have a row count of 0 then either your query is suspect or you are not filling your DataTable as mentioned before.

Comment: @har07 @Mark I have my `.Fill` method at form load. But I am declaring it on a module as `Public tablePiglet As New DataTable` - will the `New` word erasing its value? although I have .Fill on form load. And on other forms, I also use it plus DGV and it displays what I want.

Answer (score 2):

I have worked my way through this, thank you for helping.

```
Dim query As String = "SELECT * FROM tblPiglets WHERE Week=@week AND SowOrder=@so AND PigletNumber=@pig"

    Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(query, con)
        With cmd.Parameters
            .AddWithValue("@week", txtWeek.Text)
            .AddWithValue("@so", txtSo.Text)
            .AddWithValue("@pig", txtPiglet.Text)
        End With
        Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        While dr.Read
            Dim loc As String
            loc = dr("CurrentLocation").ToString()
            If loc = ComboBox1.Text Then
                confirmed()
            Else
                invalid()
            End If
        End While
    End Using
```

I was looking for the  `.Read` [function](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308278).